# Surface integral using Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

$$
\int_\Gamma y\,dx+z\,dy+x\,dz
$$
when

$\Gamma$ $= \{ (x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=9\}$ $\cap$ $x+y+z=0$

There's a theorem that states:
$\int_S(\nabla \times \vec F)\cdot d \vec S$= $\int_S(\nabla \times \vec F)\cdot \vec n\cdot d \vec S$

So, according to Stokes' theorem, I calculate $ \partial F $= $dx \wedge dy + dy\wedge dz + dz \wedge dx$.
I want the surface $S$ to be the plane $x+y+z=0$ inside the sphere, so I calculate its normal vector: $$\vec n = (\frac {1} {\sqrt3},\frac {1} {\sqrt3},\frac {1} {\sqrt3})$$
If I place $\partial F$ and $\vec n$ in the equation above, I will have $\frac {1} {\sqrt3}\int(x+y+z)\,dS$, and this is supposed to equal $0$ because $x+y+z=0$.

But the answer is not $0$, so  what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your mistake seems to have been in the computation of the curl of the vector field whose line integral you are evaluating.

Supposing $\vec{F}=\langle y,z,x\rangle$, then

$$\nabla\times\vec{F}=\langle -1,-1,-1\rangle.$$

Let $S= \{ (x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=9\}$. This is the sphere of radius $3$ centered at the origin. The plane $x+y+z=0$ cuts this sphere into two hemispheres. Let $H$ be the hemisphere on the same side of the plane as the normal vector $\vec{n}=\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\rangle$.

$$\int_\Gamma ydx+zdy+xdz=\iint_{H}(\nabla\times\vec{F})\cdot\vec{n}\,\mathrm{d}S=-\sqrt{3}\iint_{H}\mathrm{d}S=-\sqrt{3}(2\pi9)\\=-18\sqrt{3}\pi,$$

where in the second to last step we've simply used the fact that the surface area of a hemisphere of radius $r$ is $2\pi r^2$, or half that of a sphere of radius $r$.

Comment: If the plane didn't conveniently divide the sphere into two hemispheres, let's say the plane was  $M: x+y+z=1$. How would you solve it then? I'm trying to practice parameterization, hence the question.

Comment: @guyuzB Then the plane would cut the sphere into two uneven spherical segments, the smaller of which is usually called a [spherical cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html). The answer practically the same: $-\sqrt{3}\, S$, where $S$ is the surface area of the cap.

Comment: If the chosen surface is the plane $x+y+z=0$, then why in the second to last step the surface area of the hemisphere is calculated.

Comment: I guess since the intersection is a disc, hence $\displaystyle \iint _HdS=$ Area of the disc rather than the surface area of the hemisphere, which should be $-\sqrt{3}\pi 9$